# Cache response from webservice with session and timestamp in request

Tags: ios, nsurlcache

I need to cache responses from a webservice in iOS that I retrieve with URLs that include a session-id and timestamp.
Can I achieve this with nsurlcache or any other mechanism?

Thanks a lot